# JSON data error in ColdFusion 9

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

My JSON Data in ColdFusion 9 is giving an error on this line

```
Internationally renowned for its coverage of major events.
```

Now if I remove the word '*its*' then it works all right.

I pasted the JSON data in sublime text editor and the the text looks different. See the attached image

[image]

the word '*its*' has become '*itEMs*'.

Can anyone please tell me what is going on here and how to handle it?

Comment: it sounds like there's a hidden character in your its... have you tried re-typing its in there, make sure it's just those 3 chars?

Comment: abut that. the content is coming from database and I cannot control that at the moment. Is there a way to strip them programatically?

Comment: try some string functions... I'm no CF programmer, but there's a slew of string functions... binary decode/encode might be worth a try... There's the Asc function, which will give you the ordinal value of an  ascii character... The trick is finding the character, then you can easily replace it with the Replace method... http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions-pt0_18.html

Comment: Thanks. Wrote a regex to replace the high ascii value [^\t\n\r\x20-\x7E] and it worked for me. If you write this as an answer then I will accept it. Might help others.

Comment: How are you generating the JSON? Are you using JSStringFormat() to escape the string?

Comment: Just so we can see if this is a bug in how CF deals with JSON, can you pls post the exact error message, plus a stand-alone reproduction case that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Also post the json file

Answer (score 0):

try some string functions... I'm no CF programmer, but there's a slew of string functions... binary decode/encode might be worth a try... There's the Asc function, which will give you the ordinal value of an ascii character... The trick is finding the character, then you can easily replace it with the Replace method... http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions-pt0_18.html